# Do std::pmr or boost have an allocator suitable for circular/ring buffer use where allocations are of fixed size?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator, c++pmr

As far as I understand both boost and pmr have a ["bump" allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) that is suitable for many small allocations where you drop them all at once at the end(it does not actually bother with freeing when delete is called and alloc is a simple pointer increment so it is very fast).

What I wonder if there is an allocator that **does** bother to remember free blocks, but it is optimized for exact size of allocations.

something like

```
block_allocator<4096>// only use this allocator to allocate 4096 bytes, anything smaller or larger will fail.
```

In other words he does not need to work with multiple [size-classes](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/tcmalloc.html), but he is able to handle 1 billion new/deletes if you do new new new(3 times is an example) then delete delete delete because he reuses the freed blocks(assuming he has space to allocate 3 blocks).

note: I know that some std:: containers do not just allocate T and that this allocator is not suitable for this. 
I just want to use this to create many `unique_ptr<T, alloc<sizeof<T>>` (T ctor does no allocation).

Also it would be nice if he could be policy tailored to either use global new or preallocated storage or hybrid of first 2 options.

Comment: How is this different from having a fixed-size block allocator with a known number of blocks?

Comment: I am really confused about terminology, so I am not sure what you are asking. If you are asking why I do not use some allocator please provide link to his documentation. If you are asking why I am not manually using some allocator strategy: I do not want to implement anything myself.

Comment: You mentioned Boost, so I had assumed you had investigated it. I was basically asking why you don't just use their [Pool library.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html)

Comment: I have found that but I still can not figure out from documentation if they reuse freed blocks or no.

Comment: I will write a small godbolt example and check :)

Comment: If it didn't reuse free blocks, what would be the purpose of a [free list?](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html#boost_pool.pool.pooling.simple)

Comment: You are right. :) Took me a million years to figure out that malloc has a precondition instead of it returning null or throwing... Big thanks to Boris for his free boost book.
https://godbolt.org/z/gyUzX9